# get user document from mongodb on server startup

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

This Meteor server code needs to get a user document at start up.

```js
//server.js
let curs = Meteor.users.find({'name':'jack'});
```

Meteor is fired from the commend line like this:

```
MONGO_URL="mongodb://username:password@host" meteor --port 7001
```

Which gives the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined

Any idea how to get a user document on server start up?

Comment: Are you sure you have added the meteor accounts package?
Check in `\projectdir\.meteor\packages` you can see `accounts-password`  listed

Comment: @JeremyK no it is not added since this is only a server side code "micro service". But after adding it, works fine. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined

means that the variable before `find` is undefined.
In this case, the undefined variable is `Meteor.users`

This is defined in meteor's `accounts-base` package as documented [here](https://guide.meteor.com/accounts.html#accounts-base).
When you added `accounts-password` it also added `accounts-base` as it is a dependency, and after that `Meteor.users` exists (is defined) and your code will work as you expect.